# I am trying to append PFGeoPoint from parse into array and convert into CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geopoints

I have multiple PFGeoPoints in parse an I want to import all of them, and append them to an array, so at the end it will be an array of geopoints i.e. [ [21,13], [45,67] ]. And I want to convert it to CLLocationCoordinate2D, but I get an error.
Error is `value of type [PFGeoPoint] has no member 'latitude'`

```
 var points: [[PFGeoPoint]] = [[PFGeoPoint]]()

 if let coor = object["Point"] as? [PFGeoPoint]{

                            self.points.append(coordinates)
                            print("points \(self.points)")
                            self.map.reloadInputViews()

                            for(var i = 0; i < self.points.count; i++){

                                let lonlat = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.points[i].latitude), longitude: (self.points[i].longitude)!)
                                self.coordinatelocation.append(lonlat)
                                print("lonlat \(self.coordinatelocation)")
                                if(self.coordinatelocation.count == self.points.count){
                                   break
                                }

                        }

                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message already gives you answer

> value of type [PFGeoPoint] has no member 'latitude'

Your `points` is a variable with type `[[PFGeoPoint]]`, a 2D array (array inside another array).

`self.points[i]` doesn't give you `PFGeoPoint`, it gives you a `[PFGeoPoint]`.

What you need to do is `self.points[i][something].latitude`

Comment: What would that something be? would it be 0 or 1?

Comment: Edit your question to show what is `object`, it seems like you are parsing it wrongly.